# Does "switch me chairs" mean "switch chairs for me"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, ditransitive-verbs

[Eminem — The Real Slim Shady](https://genius.com/Eminem-the-real-slim-shady-lyrics):

> *So you can sit me here next to Britney Spears?
>
> Yo, shit, Christina Aguilera better **switch me chairs***

**(1a)** *Switch me chairs*.
As I understand, "to switch someone something" means "to switch something for someone".
That is, (1a) means:
**(1b)** *Switch chairs for me*.

But there isn't a ditransitive usage of the verb "switch" in the dictionaries.
So the following question arises:
Is (1a) correct?

---

[cambridge.org](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/switch):
**(2)** *After the bank robbery, the gang switched cars*.
my variants:
**(2a)** *After the bank robbery, the gang switched **itself** cars*.
**(2b)** *After the bank robbery, the gang switched cars **for itself***.

Is (2a) correct?
Is (2b) correct?
Do (2a) and (2b) mean the same?

Comment: (2)a and (2)b are ungrammatical in the American English I speak.  I would understand **switch me seats** to mean "swap seats with me" though I've never heard it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the example comes from Genius, which allows anyone to edit lyrics. Thus, it's not a good source of proper English. (Song lyrics usually aren't a good source of proper English, anyway.)

Comment: Cut me some slack. *Switch me chairs* forms a near rhyme with the 3 syllables of Britney Spears, a rationale higher than correctness.

Answer (score 3):

"Switch me chairs" isn't Standard English, but in context it apparently means "switch chairs with me", meaning that Aguilera would sit in Eminem's seat and vice versa; the next two lines indicate that, after the switch, Eminem would be seated near two of Aguilera's supposed exes. (In reality the Grammys wouldn't try to seat people in the way that these lyrics suggest, but the song is obviously not trying to be realistic: this is just a literary conceit, setting up an opportunity to say something degrading about Aguilera.)

Comment: Part of what is going on is that Eminem, as the preeminent white rap music star whose lyrics indicate that he's actually quite knowledgable and smart, in a music genre that is predominantly black and is associated with low income ghetto life, is deliberately trying to sound less articulate and grammatical than he is capable of being in order to come across as authentic and as someone who has contempt for standard American English, positioning himself as an outsider. This is because rap is a genre for outsiders to critique and describe their life as outside the establishment.

Comment: @ohwilleke - Yo shizzle! Yo pullin' ma pizzle? So much to unpack there. Are you saying rappers are the opposite of 'knowledgeable and smart'?

Comment: Really not sure what ohwilleke's comment is about. Eminem had a lot less education than many black rappers: he dropped out of high school whereas the likes of Chuck D, Ice Cube, Kanye West, Wyclef Jean, DMC all attended at least some college; Tupac and Nicki Minaj got high school diplomas or GED; etc. (Although Lil Wayne reportedly dropped out of high school at 14!)

Comment: @StuartF The core point is that the use of non-Standard English in this context (and in rap generally) is intentional. It isn't a mistake or due to the inability of the rappers to realize that they are not using Standard English. Eminem isn't the only "knowledgeable and smart" rapper, and while while he has less formal education than some, his lyrics indicate that (like many of his black rapper peers) he is well read and culturally literate. The fact that he is white is relevant because it demonstrates his need for authenticity in a mostly black (at least at the time he entered it) genre.